# Appending data to file as columns for each row (Python)

Tags: python

I have a set of computations I've performed for a data file and would like to append this new information back in. If the original file is [n x m] and I have new data that is [n x 6], what would be the easiest way to append the data? For example, if you have:

```
`    Data = [(0 1 2),
         (3 4 5)]
new_data = [(1 1 1 0 0 0),
            (0 1 0 1 0 1)]
desired_result = [(0 1 2 1 1 1 0 0 0), 
                  (3 4 5 0 1 0 1 0 1)]`
```

How could this be achieved in Python? I was looking at Pandas but I'm fairly new to programming and haven't been able to figure it out yet.
At the end of this I would like to have my original "Data" file as desired_result, and I'm struggling with the portion on how to pass the new_data in correctly to the original file.

Comment: Have a look at the library `numpy`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your specific example the following code should work

```
Data = [(0,1,2),(3,4,5)]
new_data = [(1,1,1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,1,0,1)]
desired_result = [a+b for a,b in zip(Data,new_data)]
```

However, I would recommend having your data either as a [numpy.array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) or as a [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) for easier manipulation. Do you read in your data via a csv ?

Comment: Yes, I'm reading in the file as a csv. I'm struggling with how to rewrite the new file.

Comment: Then I would use pandas. The structure of your code should roughly follow import pandas as pd, df1 = pd.read_csv(filename), do computation..., get df2, df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0/1), df3.to_csv()

Answer (score 0):

Since what you have here is a list of tuples, you could just the tuples from each list like so:

```py
Data = [(0, 1, 2),(3, 4, 5)]
new_data = [(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)]

# Im assmuming this is how you meant to format the data, please comment if I'm wrong, as I can't leave a comment on your post

expected_result = []

for i in range(len(Data)):
    # Add tuples from each list and append result to a new list
    expected_result.append(Data[i] + new_data[i])

print(expected_result)
```

This results in:

```
[(0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)]
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot a crucial detail. The "Data" is it's own file and I need to append this "new_data" into the original "Data" file. This is the portion I am struggling with.